# Eloquent - Has() with constraint

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How do I add a constraint to the *has()* method on eloquent ?

Let's say, it want to retrieve all posts with at least 3 comments from John. How can I do that ?

Non-working example of expected code:

```
$posts = Post::has('comments', '>=', 3)->where('author', 'John')->get();
```

Can I achieve the same result another way (not using *has()*)?

Comment: Are you asking how to add constraints to has(), or how to do the same thing that has() does, but without using it?

Comment: If possible, constraint with the has(). If impossible, same thing without the has().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but  could work:

```
Post::whereHas('comments', function($q){
    $q->whereAuthor('John')
      ->groupBy('post_id')
      ->havingRaw('count(`comments`.`post_id`) >= 3')
})->get();
```

Comment: Getting this error from mySql - Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression

Comment: On database config, just changed the mysql strict to false, and it works